# How to make expanding bookmarks in PDF Xchange viewer

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I use PDF Xchange viewer for all my pdfs and I love how the bookmarks expand like folders, but I don't know how to make them like that myself. Can anyone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to find how to do this either, but there are many bookmark options in Advanced>Bookmarks. All of these are only available in Pro, however. If I find a way to do this in the free version, then I'll post it here.

EDIT:
Found it. You can click and drag a comment to make it a sub-bookmark under a previous comment.

EDIT2: It's hard to show a click and drag with a picture, but here is an attempt. When you have the bookmark panel open, you can click and drag a particular bookmark or comment and an orange line shows up indicating where the new placement will be.

[image: Here]

Here I'm moving 11.1.1 to the same hierarchical level as 11.1.

Comment: Linked in a comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have found there is a keyboard shortcut, as well. If you highlight a bookmark, you can indent it with ALT-right, and undo that indent with ALT-left. Further, collapse or expand a section with the left and right arrow keys, and create a new section with the insert key (it takes account of the current screen position for the bookmark).